# How can I install clang-format in Ubuntu?

Tags: vim, clang, code-formatting, clang-format

I am trying to use clang-tools in particular clang-format for automatic code formatting in vim but I couldn't find this tool with apt-get search.

Is there anybody experienced this problem before, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What do you see when your run `sudo apt-cache search clang-format`?

Comment: actually apt-get could not find it and then i added ubuntu-saucy to the my repository list and it found clang-format.

Comment: I just added instructions [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56879394/4561887) to download the _latest binary_ of `clang-format`, straight from the clang+llvm source code repository releases page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

clang-format is not available in the ubuntu-precise 12.04 but it is available in ubuntu
saucy **http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/clang-format-3.4**.

in order to find this package with the apt-cache we have to add below list into our repository list. Actually below list is generated for the singapore servers but if you want to look for your own country you can use **http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php**

After generating your list, you have to add them into your repository, you can learn how to do that by looking to here. **https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine**

The list of packages are;

```
deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted universe multiverse 

deb-src http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted universe multiverse 

deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted universe multiverse 

deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 

deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe    multiverse 

deb-src http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted universe multiverse 

deb-src http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

deb-src http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 

deb-src http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then you should search clang-format with below command first

> sudo apt-cache search clang-format

Then, you can install which version you want to install such as;

> sudo apt-get install clang-format-3.3

Comment: `sudo` is not needed for `apt-cache search`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install clang-format-3.4` worked in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. This was after typing: `sudo apt-get install clang-3.4`

Comment: I used `sudo apt install clang-format-3.6` on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: How do I get the latest version? `sudo apt install clang-format` installs clang-format version 6, but the documentation pages I can find online are for versions 9 and 11. Why is the Ubuntu version 5 major versions out of date?

Answer (score 62):

With **Ubuntu 16.04**, simply do:

```bash
sudo apt install clang-format
```

Comment: After installing this way I get `clang-format: command not found`. I proceeded to remove that `clang-format` package.

Comment: @MichaelFulton That works on `ubuntu 16.04`, not sure whether later version also works.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, the package is used by calling `clang-format-6.0` or whatever version you have.

Comment: I used `sudo apt install clang-format-3.6` on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, I used:  
    `sudo apt install clang-format-5.0`
after the installation you can try 
    `clang-format-5.0 -h` 
to check if everything went well.

Answer (score 25):

Nowadays, you can directly use `apt install clang-format` in Debian/Ubuntu to install `clang-format`. However, the `clang-format` provided by Debian/Ubuntu is quite old. For example, the latest version of `clang-format` from Ubuntu 18.04 is `v7` but the latest stable version is already reached `v12`. You can install the latest version of `clang-format` by following the steps below:

Step 1: Run `wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -`

Step 2: Append the following content at the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list` based on your operating system:

- Buster (Debian 10):

  ```
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster main
  # 11 
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster-11 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster-11 main
  # 12 
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster-12 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster-12 main
  ```
- Bullseye (Debian 11):

  ```
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/bullseye/ llvm-toolchain-bullseye main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bullseye/ llvm-toolchain-bullseye main
  # 11 
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/bullseye/ llvm-toolchain-bullseye-11 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bullseye/ llvm-toolchain-bullseye-11 main
  # 12 
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/bullseye/ llvm-toolchain-bullseye-12 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bullseye/ llvm-toolchain-bullseye-12 main
  ```
- Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04):

  ```
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial main
  # 11
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-11 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-11 main
  # 12
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-12 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-12 main
  ```
- Bionic (Ubuntu 18.04):

  ```
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic main
  # 11
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-11 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-11 main
  # 12
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-12 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-12 main
  ```
- Focal (Ubuntu 20.04)

  ```
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal main
  # 14
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-14 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-14 main
  # 15
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-15 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-15 main
  ```
- Jammy (Ubuntu 22.04)

  ```
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/jammy/ llvm-toolchain-jammy main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/jammy/ llvm-toolchain-jammy main
  # 14
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/jammy/ llvm-toolchain-jammy-14 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/jammy/ llvm-toolchain-jammy-14 main
  # 15
  deb http://apt.llvm.org/jammy/ llvm-toolchain-jammy-15 main
  deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/jammy/ llvm-toolchain-jammy-15 main
  ```

You can check https://apt.llvm.org/ if your operating system is not on this list.

Step 3: Run `sudo apt update`

Step 4: Run `apt search clang-format` and check all available versions:

```
$ sudo apt search clang-format
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
arcanist-clang-format-linter/stable 0.git20161021-2 all
  clang-format linter for Arcanist

clang-format/unknown 1:13.0-53~20210202214848.38 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code

clang-format-11/unknown 1:11.1.0~++20210203115409+1fdec59bffc1-1~exp1~20210203230038.161 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code

clang-format-12/unknown 1:12.0.0~++20210312110334+ca14f0282fce-1~exp1~20210312221110.59 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code

clang-format-13/unknown 1:13~++20210315063844+b868a3edad9d-1~exp1~20210315174553.2286 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code

clang-format-6.0/stable 1:6.0.1-10 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code

clang-format-7/stable 1:7.0.1-8+deb10u2 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
```

Step 5: Use `apt install` to install the `clang-format` you want. Then you can use `--version` to check the installed `clang-format`. You can install multiple versions of `clang-format` in a same environment.

```
$ sudo apt install -y clang-format-12
$ clang-format-12 --version
Ubuntu clang-format version 12.0.0-++20210312110334+ca14f0282fce-1~exp1~20210312221110.59

$ sudo apt install -y clang-format
$ clang-format --version
Ubuntu clang-format version 13.0.0-++20210315063844+b868a3edad9d-1~exp1~20210315174553.2286
```

Comment: Would be nice to have the source for these instructions featured more clearly (https://apt.llvm.org)

Other that that it worked great for me.

Comment: Note: Meanwhile it is also possible to install clang-format-13 and clang-format-14  on Ubuntu 18-04. See [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409032/1595591).

Comment: Hi @ocavue , I need clang-format-7, but when I follow your advice and get to

"apt search clang-format"

... Every version is there except for 7. How do I get clang-format-7?

Answer (score 12):

*This answer has been rewritten since the downvote, and is the most-up-to-date answer to this question as of Apr. 2022. It is also the only answer that explains how to get the latest version of `clang-format` direct from LLVM, the people who make it.*

### To install the latest version of `clang-format` and `git-clang-format` (runnable as `git clang-format`):

### Summary

1. To install `clang-format` in Ubuntu, you can use `sudo apt install clang-format`, or some variant of that (see below), but it frequently installs a really old version that is missing a ton of features. So:
2. [Preferred] To install *the latest version* of `clang-format` in Ubuntu, you must get it from [the official release pages on GitHub](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases) directly. I explain how to do this in detail below.

### [Old method] To install an old version of `clang-format`:

Do:

```bash
sudo apt update
```

And then try, in this order, one-at-a-time, until one works:

```bash
sudo apt install clang-format
sudo apt install clang-format-14.0
sudo apt install clang-format-13.0
sudo apt install clang-format-12.0
sudo apt install clang-format-11.0
sudo apt install clang-format-10.0
sudo apt install clang-format-9.0
sudo apt install clang-format-8.0
sudo apt install clang-format-7.0
sudo apt install clang-format-6.0
sudo apt install clang-format-5.0
sudo apt install clang-format-4.0
sudo apt install clang-format-3.6
sudo apt install clang-format-3.4
sudo apt install clang-format-3.0
```

On Ubuntu 14.04, for instance, the first command above that works is `sudo apt install clang-format-3.6`. As of Ubuntu 16.04, I believe, `sudo apt install clang-format` works, but no matter what version of Ubuntu you're on, Ubuntu 20.04 included, `sudo apt install clang-format` installs a quite-outdated version (ex: version 6.0.0 on Ubuntu 18.04). So, to get the latest version of `clang-format`, keep reading.

### [*Preferred method*] How to install the *latest* version of `clang-format` on Ubuntu

#### The super quick instructions to get a recent version

To get `clang-format` and `git-clang-format` from LLVM (the parent organization which makes the `clang` C and C++ compiler, as well as those tools) directly, follow my instructions farther below. However, that requires downloading the entire compressed `clang` compiler toolset release which is ~600 MB, and extracting it into a folder which is ~5 GB when fully extracted, just so you can copy out a *couple megabytes* of these executables. That takes some time.

So, if you're in a huge hurry, *and* if you want to trust executables from my personal repo, I keep a recent version (14.0.0 or later) of both `clang-format` and `git-clang-format` in the `bin` dir of my repo here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter/tree/main/bin. It is frequently *not* recommended to trust other peoples' executables, however, so I provide the *exact* method and instructions below which I used to extract those executables from the original release from LLVM (the maker of `clang-format`), which you can follow yourself if you like instead.

**If you'd like to quickly download and install `clang-format` and `git-clang-format` from my personal repo, do this:**

```bash
wget https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter/raw/main/bin/clang-format
wget https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter/raw/main/bin/git-clang-format
chmod +x clang-format git-clang-format
mkdir -p ~/bin
mv clang-format ~/bin
mv git-clang-format ~/bin

# log out of Ubuntu and log back in

# ensure it worked and you now have a later version
clang-format --version  

# Check the help menus
clang-format -h
git clang-format -h
# OR (same thing as the line just above):
git-clang-format -h
```

#### The full instructions to get the *latest* version *from LLVM, the makers, directly:*

This requires downloading the entire LLVM `clang` C and C++ compiler toolset, which is a compressed file ~600 MB in size, and then extracting it into a folder which is ~5 GB in size when extracted, just so you can copy out a few magabytes of executables from within it.

*These instructions were originally posted in the README of my eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter repo here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter#installation-instructions*

**The full steps to get the latest `clang-format` and `git-clang-format` from the latest official LLVM release:**

1. Go to the LLVM official clang releases page: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases
2. Find the latest binary release for your operating system. Example: for 64-bit Linux, it is currently (as of Mar. 2022): **clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz**. The download link is: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-14.0.0/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz
3. Use the link you found above for the next commands:

   ```bash
   url="https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-14.0.0/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz"
   # download it; be patient: the file is ~600 MB
   wget "$url"
   # extract it; be patient: this could take several minutes, as the file is
   # about 5 GB when extracted! On my high-speed computer with SSD, it took
   # ~1 minute
   time tar xf clang+llvm*.tar.xz
   # cd into the bin dir
   cd clang+llvm*/bin
   # make a ~/bin dir if it doesn't exist yet
   mkdir -p ~/bin
   # copy out `clang-format` into your ~/bin dir
   cp clang-format ~/bin
   # copy out `git-clang-format` into your ~/bin dir
   cp git-clang-format ~/bin

   # Manually edit your ~/.profile file to ensure it contains the following in
   # order to ensure ~/bin is part of your executable PATH variable. This is
   # part of your default Ubuntu ~/.profile file (for which you have a backup
   # copy in /etc/skel/.profile):
   #
   #       # set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
   #       if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
   #           PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
   #       fi

   # Now, if this is your first time creating and using the ~/bin dir, log out
   # of Ubuntu and log back in. 

   # check your clang-format version to ensure it shows the version you just
   # installed
   clang-format --version
   # Ensure it is found in your ~/bin dir; my output to this command is:
   # `/home/gabriel/bin/clang-format`
   which clang-format
   # Check `git-clang-format` too
   which git-clang-format

   # Check the help menus
   clang-format -h
   git clang-format -h
   # OR (same thing as the line just above):
   git-clang-format -h

   # manually delete the the extracted folder if desired, and the
   # downloaded *.tar.xz file as well, if desired
   ```

Note that `git` has a pretty neat feature that causes *any* executable in your path which begins with `git-` to automatically be treated as a `git` command. Whenever you run `git some_command`, `git` automatically searches all of your system's `PATH` variable for an executable named `git-some_command`. If it exists, `git` runs it. So, simply by virtue of the fact that you put an executable in your path named `git-clang-format`, `git` allows you to run it as `git clang-format` (withOUT the dash after `git`). Optionally, of course, you can also just run that same executable as `git-clang-format`, since that's what its filename is.

See below for recommended `git clang-format` usage and workflow.

### Additional setup & usage info & resources:

1. If you followed the steps just above, you now have the latest version fo both `clang-format` *and* `git-clang-format`. Having the latter allows you to run `git clang-format` as a `git` command to auto-format your files before you commit them in `git`. `git-clang-format` is a Python script written by LLVM, the makers of the `clang` C and C++ compiler and `clang-format`. It is located in the official LLVM GitHub repository here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/tools/clang-format/git-clang-format. Place it into your PATH; ex: in a file called `~/bin/git-clang-format`, and mark this file as executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/git-clang-format`).

   1. The **recommended `git` workflow to call and use this `git-clang-format` auto-formatter** would then be:

      ```bash
      # See what git changes you have
      git difftool  
      # OR: `git diff` if you haven't configured a difftool such as meld
      git diff
      # Add (stage) a C or C++ file to be committed
      git add my_changed_file.c 

      # Run `git-clang-format` to have `clang-format` check and
      # auto-format **just your changed lines**. (This runs the
      # `~/bin/git-clang-format` Python script).
      git clang-format
      # See what changes `clang-format` just made to your changed lines
      git difftool
      # OR
      git diff

      # Add (stage) this file again since it's been changed by
      # `git-clang-format`
      git add my_changed_file.c 

      # commit the changed file
      git commit
      ```
2. Other, potentially-useful info.:

   1. `git-clang-format` python script setup instructions: https://dx13.co.uk/articles/2015/4/3/Setting-up-git-clang-format.html
   2. `git clang-format` usage and workflow instructions: https://electronjs.org/docs/development/clang-format
3. Update Apr. 2020: I just got `clang-format` up and running fully on a project on GitHub. I run it with `./run_clang-format.sh`; here's how:

   1. I wrote some instructions here: https://github.com/AmboVent-1690-108/AmboVent#setup
   2. Here's the PR where I added everything: https://github.com/AmboVent-1690-108/AmboVent/pull/39. You can take a look to see how I did it all.
   3. I borrowed from my notes and files I have in my dotfiles project here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/clang-format

### Related

1. See also my `clang-format`-based project here: [eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter)

Answer (score 5):

`pip3 install clang-format` gives me the latest version 9.0 on ubuntu 18.04 with zero configuration

Comment: I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'"  ?

So, you need this too: "pip3 install scikit-build", and not in the same step.

Comment: This is a great answer, especially in combination with the fact that the PyPi package also offers a pre-commit hook and allows selecting specific clang-format versions: https://pypi.org/project/clang-format/

Comment: The state of software distribution on Linux... where `pip` is the best way to install `clang-format`  I've also found it is the best way to install the latest CMake if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use command below:

```
sudo apt-get install clang-format
```

It works in ubuntu16.04(install Setting up clang-format-3.8 (1:3.8-2ubuntu4))

when I try

```
sudo apt-cache search clang-format
# it return 
clang-format - Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
clang-format-3.5 - Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
clang-format-3.6 - Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
clang-format-3.7 - Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
clang-format-3.8 - Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
clang-format-3.9 - Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
clang-format-4.0 - Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
clang-format-5.0 - Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
clang-format-6.0 - Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
clang-format-8 - Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
```

then try

```
sudo apt-get install clang-format-8
```

There is no command clang-format in ENV

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
python3 -m pip install --user clang-format
```

This will install a precompiled binary from https://pypi.org/project/clang-format/. It is quite practical if you don't have `sudo` access, or if you need clang-format for a pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 1):

This is an update, because I had troubles with the suggestions above on **Ubuntu 21.04**

`sudo apt install clang-format` installs v.12 and I needed anything older.

`sudo apt install clang-format-9.0` won't work.
("Package wasn't found")

This worked fine:
`sudo apt install clang-format-9`

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about another Linux distribution. But just in case, for openSUSE, to install `clang-format`, you have to run this:

```bash
zypper in clang-tools
```