# How to call clang-format over a cpp project folder?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

Is there a way to call something like `clang-format --style=Webkit` for an entire cpp project folder, rather than running it separately for each file?

I am using `clang-format.py` and `vim` to do this, but I assume there is a way to apply this once.

Comment: See also GitHub-issue ["request: clang-format to recurse over directories #62108"](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/62108)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

What about:

```
clang-format -i -style=WebKit *.cpp *.h
```

in the project folder. The -i option makes it inplace (by default formatted output is written to stdout).

Comment: or if you are using a config file and want to format multiple file types:

`clang-format-3.6 -i -style=file *.cpp *.h *.hpp`

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: Yes, *.cpp will be expanded by the shell. clang just needs a list of files. More advanced options (like recursive globbing) depend on the features of your shell. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/recursive-glob on how to use `**` construct.

Comment: What about with `clang-tidy`?

Comment: @AaronFranke Using `*.cpp` to generate a list of files should work. The `clang-tidy` command allows passing multiple files. 
`
USAGE: clang-tidy [options] <source0> [... <sourceN>]

`
In practice that may not be the best way, though. Clang-tidy performs a much deeper analysis, so it requires the compiler flags for each file etc. When I used clang-tidy, I usually had a "compilation database" – a JSON file with the commands for each file and some script which went over it. It was a couple years back, maybe there is a better way now.

Comment: What if my C++ files are in subfolders?

Comment: You can use `**`. See: unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/recursive-glob.

Comment: does not work for me - only get `invalid argument` errors. Even with double `-` on `style`

Comment: @vlad_tepesch What exactly doesn't work? What command are you running exactly and what is the full error message (you might want to use pastebin for that)?

Answer (score 164):

Unfortunately, there is no way to apply clang-format recursively. `*.cpp` will only match files in the current directory, not subdirectories. Even `**/*` doesn't work.

Luckily, there is a solution: grab all the file names with the `find` command and pipe them in. For example, if you want to format all `.h` and `.cpp` files in the directory `foo/bar/` recursively, you can do

```
find foo/bar/ -iname *.h -o -iname *.cpp | xargs clang-format -i
```

See [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/37232) for additional discussion.

Comment: Well, `**/*.cpp` seems to work in (reasonably modern) bash. You may need to `shopt -s globstar` before.

Comment: If you are using CMake, [this post](http://www.labri.fr/perso/fleury/posts/programming/using-clang-tidy-and-clang-format.html) shows you how you can use CMake's [`GLOB_RECURSE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) to find all `.cpp` files and pass them to `clang-format`.

Comment: The combination of `find` and `xargs` should use `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0 ...` to ensure that all types of filenames are handled correctly.

Comment: This command fails if any .cpp or .h files exist in pwd. `find foo/bar/ -iname '*.h' -o -iname '*.cpp' | xargs clang-format -i` will fix the issue.

Comment: @nyanpasu64 It will also fail in `zsh`. I actually don't understand why it doesn't fail in bash. :-) Those quotes should be really there so why does it even work without them in bash.

Comment: I wrote a reusable POSIX sh script to identify C and/or C++ file paths as a workaround. I really wish clang-format would go ahead and implement built-in project recursion :/ https://github.com/mcandre/sail

Comment: Here's archive to the post on using GLOB_RECURSE https://web.archive.org/web/20190727093603/http://www.labri.fr/perso/fleury/posts/programming/using-clang-tidy-and-clang-format.html

Answer (score 53):

First create a `.clang-format` file if it doesn't exist:

```
clang-format -style=WebKit -dump-config > .clang-format
```

Choose whichever predefined style you like, or edit the resulting `.clang-format` file.

[clang-format configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/) is helpful.

Then run:

```
find . -regex '.*\.\(cpp\|hpp\|cc\|cxx\)' -exec clang-format -style=file -i {} \;
```

Other file extensions than `cpp`, `hpp`, `cc` and `cxx` can be used in the regular expression, just make sure to separate them with `\|`.

Comment: For `-style=file` is there a way to specify a custom file path? I tried `-style=~/.clang-format` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Not that I know of, apart from changing the current directory.

Comment: The ghetto solution I came up with is to make a function which first runs `cp ~/.clang-format .` then the find command in your answer.

Comment: Interesting but it doesn't work for me on macOS. But this version (with -E flag and without escaping special symbols does):
`find -E . -regex '.*\.(cpp|hpp|cc|cxx)' -exec clang-format -style=file -i {} \;`

Comment: Thanks for the info, Anton Breusov. `-E` does not work here on Arch Linux, but `-regextype egrep` does. Does `-regextype egrep` work on macOS too?

Answer (score 15):

I recently found a bash-script which does exactly what you need:

https://github.com/eklitzke/clang-format-all

> This is a bash script that will run `clang-format -i` on your code.
>
> Features:
>
> - Finds the right path to `clang-format` on Ubuntu/Debian, which encode the LLVM version in the `clang-format` filename
> - Fixes files recursively
> - Detects the most common file extensions used by C/C++ projects

On Windows, I used it successfully in Git Bash and WSL.

Answer (score 10):

For the Windows users: If you have Powershell 3.0 support, you can do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Directory -Recurse |
    foreach {
        cd $_.FullName
        &clang-format -i -style=WebKit *.cpp
    }
```

*Note1: Use `pushd .` and `popd` if you want to have the same current directory before and after the script*

*Note2: The script operates in the current working directory*

*Note3: This can probably be written in a single line if that was really important to you*

Answer (score 9):

When you use Windows (CMD) but don't want to use the PowerShell cannon to shoot this fly, try this:

```
for /r %t in (*.cpp *.h) do clang-format -i -style=WebKit "%t"
```

Don't forget to duplicate the two `%`s if in a cmd script.

Answer (score 7):

The below script and process:

1. works in **Linux**
2. should work on **MacOS**
3. works in **Windows** inside [Git For Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) terminal with `clang-format` [downloaded and installed](https://llvm.org/builds/).

Here's how I do it:

I create a `run_clang_format.sh` script and place it in the root of my project directory, then I run it from anywhere. Here's what it looks like:

[**run_clang_format.sh**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter/blob/main/run_clang-format.sh)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

THIS_PATH="$(realpath "$0")"
THIS_DIR="$(dirname "$THIS_PATH")"

# Find all files in THIS_DIR which end in .ino, .cpp, etc., as specified
# in the regular expression just below
FILE_LIST="$(find "$THIS_DIR" | grep -E ".*(\.ino|\.cpp|\.c|\.h|\.hpp|\.hh)$")"

echo -e "Files found to format = \n\"\"\"\n$FILE_LIST\n\"\"\""

# Format each file.
# - NB: do NOT put quotes around `$FILE_LIST` below or else the `clang-format` command will 
#   mistakenly see the entire blob of newline-separated file names as a SINGLE file name instead 
#   of as a new-line separated list of *many* file names!
clang-format --verbose -i --style=file $FILE_LIST
```

Using `--style=file` means that I must also have a custom `.clang-format` clang-format specifier file at this same level, which I do.

Now, make your newly-created `run_clang_format.sh` file executable:

```bash
chmod +x run_clang_format.sh
```

...and run it:

```bash
./run_clang_format.sh
```

Here's a sample run and output for me:

```bash
~/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer$ ./run_clang-format.sh 
Files found to format = 
"""
/home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/examples/PPM_Writer_demo/PPM_Writer_demo.ino
/home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/examples/PPM_Writer_demo2/PPM_Writer_demo2.ino
/home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/src/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer.h
/home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/src/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer.cpp
/home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/src/timers/eRCaGuy_TimerCounterTimers.h
"""
Formatting /home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/examples/PPM_Writer_demo/PPM_Writer_demo.ino
Formatting /home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/examples/PPM_Writer_demo2/PPM_Writer_demo2.ino
Formatting /home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/src/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer.h
Formatting /home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/src/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer.cpp
Formatting /home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/src/timers/eRCaGuy_TimerCounterTimers.h
```

You can find my [`run_clang_format.sh`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/blob/master/run_clang-format.sh) file in my [eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer) repository, and in my [eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter) repository too. My [`.clang-format` file is there too](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter).

### References:

1. My repository:

   1. Update: see here instead: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter
   2. [eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer) repo
   3. [`run_clang_format.sh` file](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer/blob/master/run_clang-format.sh)
2. My notes on how to use `clang-format` in my ["git & Linux cmds, help, tips & tricks - Gabriel.txt"](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/git%20%26%20Linux%20cmds%2C%20help%2C%20tips%20%26%20tricks%20-%20Gabriel.txt) doc in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo (search the document for "clang-format").
3. Official `clang-format` documentation, setup, instructions, etc! https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html
4. Download the `clang-format` auto-formatter/linter executable for Windows, or other installers/executables here: https://llvm.org/builds/
5. Clang-Format Style Options: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html
6. [my answer] [How do I get the directory where a Bash script is located from within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-to-get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself/60157372#60157372)

### Related:

1. [my answer] [Indenting preprocessor directives with clang-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476165/indenting-preprocessor-directives-with-clang-format/66004745#66004745)

### See also:

1. [my answer] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678531/fixing-a-simple-c-code-without-the-coments/67678570#67678570

Answer (score 3):

In modern bash you can recursively crawl the file tree

```
for file_name in ./src/**/*.{cpp,h,hpp}; do
    if [ -f "$file_name" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$file_name"
        clang-format -i $file_name
    fi
done
```

Here the source is assumed to be located in `./src` and the `.clang-format` contains the formatting information.

Comment: I don't think globstar is on by default in bash, so you'd need to set it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that searches recursively and pipes all files to clang-format as a file list in one command. It also excludes the "build" directory (I use CMake), but you can just omit the "grep" step to remove that.

```
shopt -s globstar extglob failglob && ls **/*.@(h|hpp|hxx|c|cpp|cxx) | grep -v build | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs clang-format -i
```

Answer (score 2):

As @sbarzowski touches on in a comment above, in bash you can enable [globstar](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) which causes `**` to expand recursively.

If you just want it for this one command you can do something like the following to format all `.h`, `.cc` and `.cpp` files.

```sh
(shopt -s globstar; clang-format -i **/*.{h,cc,cpp})
```

Or you can add `shopt -s globstar` to your `.bashrc` and have `**` goodness all the time in bash.

As a side note, you may want to use `--dry-run` with clang-format the first time to be sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this inside a Make file. It uses `git ls-files --exclude-standard` to get the list of the files, so that means untracked files are automatically skipped. It assumes that you have a `.clang-tidy` file at your project root.

```
format:
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
    pwsh -c '$$files=(git ls-files --exclude-standard); foreach ($$file in $$files) { if ((get-item $$file).Extension -in ".cpp", ".hpp", ".c", ".cc", ".cxx", ".hxx", ".ixx") { clang-format -i -style=file $$file } }'
else
    git ls-files --exclude-standard | grep -E '\.(cpp|hpp|c|cc|cxx|hxx|ixx)$$' | xargs clang-format -i -style=file
endif
```

Run with `make format`

Notice that I escaped `$` using `$$` for make.

If you use go-task instead of make, you will need this:

```yaml
  format:
    - |
      {{if eq OS "windows"}} 
        powershell -c '$files=(git ls-files --exclude-standard); foreach ($file in $files) { if ((get-item $file).Extension -in ".cpp", ".hpp", ".c", ".cc", ".cxx", ".hxx", ".ixx") { clang-format -i -style=file $file } }' 
      {{else}} 
        git ls-files --exclude-standard | grep -E '\.(cpp|hpp|c|cc|cxx|hxx|ixx)$' | xargs clang-format -i -style=file 
      {{end}}
```

Run with `task format`

If you want to run the individual scripts, then use these

```
# powershell
$files=(git ls-files --exclude-standard); foreach ($file in $files) { if ((get-item $file).Extension -in ".cpp", ".hpp", ".c", ".cc", ".cxx", ".hxx", ".ixx") { clang-format -i -style=file $file } }
```

```sh
# bash
git ls-files --exclude-standard | grep -E '\.(cpp|hpp|c|cc|cxx|hxx|ixx)$' | xargs clang-format -i -style=file
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following command to format all objective-C files under the current folder **recursively**:

```
$ find . -name "*.m" -o -name "*.h" | sed 's| |\\ |g' | xargs clang-format -i
```

I've defined the following alias in my `.bash_profile` to make things easier:

```
# Format objC files (*.h and *.m) under the current folder, recursively
alias clang-format-all="find . -name \"*.m\" -o -name \"*.h\" | sed 's| |\\ |g' | xargs clang-format -i"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also consider [`git-clang-format`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#git-integration). It might be closer to what you need on a day-to-day basis.

`git-clang-format` formats all your *changed* C/C++ files in the current Git repository. There are some good tutorials [here](https://ortogonal.github.io/cpp/git-clang-format/) and [here](https://offlinemark.com/2021/04/02/surgical-formatting-with-git-clang-format/) but in summary, once `clang`'s `bin` directory is in your `PATH`:

To see what changes will be made:

```
git clang-format --diff
```

And to actually make the changes:

```
git clang-format --force
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit <O/T>, but when I googled "how to feed a list of files into `clang-format`" this was the top hit.  In my case, I don't want to recurse over an entire directory for a specific file type.  Instead, I want to apply `clang-format` to all the files I edited *before* I push my feature/bugfix branch.  The first step in our pipeline is `clang-format`, and it almost always fails, so I wanted to run this "manually" on my changes just to take care of that step instead of nearly always dealing with a quickly failing pipeline.  You can get a list of all the files you changed with

```
git diff <commitOrTagToCompareTo> --name-only
```

And borrowing from [Antimony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36046965/3476780), you can pipe that into `xargs` and finally `clang-format`:

```
git diff <commitOrTagToCompareTo> --name-only | xargs clang-format -i
```

Running `git status` will now show which files changed (`git diff(tool)` will show you the changes), and you can commit and push this up, hopefully moving on to more important parts of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to find out header and source files, we use:

```
find . -path ./build -prune -o -iname "*.hpp" -o -iname "*.cpp" -o -iname "*.c" -o -iname "*.h"
```

The **-o** is for "or" and **-iname** is for ignoring case. And in your case specifically, you may add more extensions like **-o -iname "*.cc"**. Here another trick is to escape ./build/ directory, **-path ./build -prune** suggests do not descend into the given directory "./build".
Type above command you will find it still prints out "./build", then we use sed command to replace "./build" with empty char, something like:

```
sed 's/.\/build//' <in stream>
```

At last, we call clang-format to do formatting:

```
clang-format -i <file>
```

Combine them, we have:

```
find . -path ./build -prune -o -iname "*.hpp" -o -iname "*.cpp" -o -iname "*.cc" -o -iname "*.cxx" -o -iname "*.c" -o -iname "*.h"|sed 's/.\/build//'|xargs clang-format -i
```

Comment: This can be unsafe, consider using print0 with xargs -0

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where I needed to check for formatting errors, but I wanted to do it with a single clang-format invocation both on linux and windows.

Here are my one-liners:

Bash:

`find $PWD/src -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec clang-format -style=file --dry-run --Werror {} +`

Powershell:

`clang-format -style=file --dry-run --Werror $(Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD/src -Recurse | Where Name -Match '\.(?:h|cpp)$' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)`

Answer (score 0):

This command will help you to find *.h & *.cpp from all the subfolders and also to update the files with our customize clang format file, which is in Foo/Boo

find ../src/ -iname *.h -o -iname *.cpp | xargs clang-format  -style=file:"Foo/Boo/.clang-format" -i

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I checked these answers , and they all failed for me. (Some of them were not for Windows). So my solution in PowerShell that worked for me is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.cpp |
     foreach {
         & 'C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-format.exe' -i -style=file --fallback-style=Google $_.FullName
     }

Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.h |
     foreach {
         & 'C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-format.exe' -i -style=file --fallback-style=Google $_.FullName
     }
```