# Is there a way to call clang-format on every .cpp and .h file in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, clang-format

I've tried [the Visual Studio plugin](http://llvm.org/builds/) but you have to select the code you want to apply clang to and then call the formatter. So `CTRL+A` `CTRL+R` `CTRL+F` for each and every file.

Is there a way to do that for the whole project and/or whole solution without manually going through each file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call clang-format over a cpp project folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896909/how-to-call-clang-format-over-a-cpp-project-folder)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this by reference to a Visual Studio project, but this should be possible by calling `clang-format` from the command line to format everything in the folder:

`clang-format style=llvm *.h *.cpp`

More information [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

Answer (score -1):

Example: `clang-format -i **/*.cc **/*.h`

Adapt to the file format of your project files, like replacing `cc` with `cpp`