# What is the "project folder" or "project root" when using clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

What is the "project folder" when using clang-format?

I googled around but people just use the term without clear definition.
For instance in stackoverflow:
[How to call clang-format over a cpp project folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896909/how-to-call-clang-format-over-a-cpp-project-folder)

For instance in the official document, the term "project root" is used but what is this?
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one.  According to the sources you yourself link to, clang-format just operates on a list of files provided on the command line.

The situation might change when clang-format is integrated into an IDE.  Then, you have the concept of a project, and the project root folder is usually the folder containing the project file (e.g. MyProject.vcxproj and MyProject.sln for Visual Studio, or MyProject.pbxproj for Xcode).