# How could I indent C++ pragma using clang-format?

Tags: c++, coding-style, clang-format

I am using `vim-autoformat`, which uses `clang-format` as external formatter.

It seems that `clang-format` won't indent the C++ `#pragma`. For example:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        puts("demo");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to have it formatted into :

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        puts("demo");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because traditionally preprocessor directives *had* to be starting on the first column of the line?

Comment: [Relevant bug report](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17362).

Comment: Did you find any solution (otherwise then reparsing)?

Comment: Update as of Jan 2021 -- Based on my research, it seems that clang-format 12 plans to introduce a field called `IndentPragmas` which addresses this issue. However, in the `clang-format` binary (version 12) that I build, this option does not seem implemented. Hope this provides some updates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indenting preprocessor directives with clang-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476165/indenting-preprocessor-directives-with-clang-format)

Answer (score 5):

It's been late but this is the solution you are looking for.
It formats the pragma along with the code block.

https://github.com/MedicineYeh/p-clang-format

The main concept is replacing the string so that the formatter uses the "correct" rules on these pragmas. The motivative example is as following.

```
# Replace "#pragma omp" by "//#pragma omp"
sed -i 's/#pragma omp/\/\/#pragma omp/g' ./main.c
# Do format
clang-format ./main.c
# Replace "// *#pragma omp" by "#pragma omp"
sed -i 's/\/\/ *#pragma omp/#pragma omp/g' ./main.c
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit even later, but `clang-format` is finally planning to make any workarounds unnecessary. https://reviews.llvm.org/D92753 introduces the boolean `IndentPragmas` switch to allow for indenting pragmas the same as its surrounding code.

Comment: any update on this ? is it supported yet, on what version ?