# Tell clang-format to ignore pragmas

Tags: c++, clang-format

clang-format currently moves all pragmas to the first column. An example before clang-format:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  #pragma UNROLL
  // ...some code...
}
```

The same code after clang-format:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
#pragma UNROLL
  // ...some code...
}
```

Is there a way to have clang-format ignore pragma lines entirely without changing the source code (i.e. without cluttering the source with `// clang-format off`)? For example with a regular expression?

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31353748/2949968) (I would like to avoid [installing a third-party tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45158979/2949968)), and will hopefully be resolved by [this bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36020).

---

Additionally, while `clang-format off` is respected for the line with the pragma, the commented line *itself* will get indented to what the pragma *would have been indented to* (with clang-format 6.0.0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
// clang-format off
  #pragma UNROLL
  // clang-format on
  // ...some code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only few pragmas that you are using, you could try to disguise them as regular commands. According to [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/), the following has the correct effect on the compiler, while the formatting is not destroyed by clang-format.

An additional benefit is, that you could use different definitions, depending on the compiler (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28737178))

```
#define UNROLL _Pragma("unroll")

void f()
{
    volatile int x = 0;
    UNROLL for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        x = x + i;
    }
}
```