# indent macros to the same width as normal source code

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, clang-format

I am encountering an issue with `clang-format`. Consider the following example header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void foo(int x);
    void foo2(int y);

#define FOO 2
#define BAR 3
  
    void bar(int z);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I would like to indent the defines (`FOO` and `BAR`) to the same level as the declarations. Is there a way to do this with `clang-format`?

---

Desired Result:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void foo(int x);
    void foo2(int y);

    #define FOO 2
    #define BAR 3
  
    void bar(int z);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: I believe some tools (??... can't remember any right now) only want the `#` on column 1

Comment: Interesting, never encountered such an issue. Would be curious to learn more if someone has more details about that

Comment: In early C standards, the `#` was mandated to be on the left.

Comment: Went to sleep with the `#` on my mind, woke up without any idea about why I keep it on column 1... just the nagging feeling about some tool (maybe it was a badly written script?)... when I want to indent preprocessing lines I put the spaces between the `#` and the rest ... `#        define OCTOTHORPE 35`

Comment: @pmg This looks like an acceptable alternative! Is there a way to achive this in clang-format?

Comment: Maybe "IndentPDirectives"?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610210/25324

Comment: IIRC IndentPDirectives does only indent nested preprocessor directives but not preprocessor directives nestend inside "regular" code.  But I can try it in a few hours

Comment: @pmg I tested your suggestion and it does ignore preprocessor directives in cases like the one above. So sadly this option wont work here