# Can I install over clang-format-10 on ubuntu18.04

Tags: clang-format

I want to know either clang-format-10 can be installed on ubuntu 18.04.
Since I have to use clang-format `--dry-run` option, so I want to know

Answer (score 3):

You can install `clang-format-10` on Ubuntu 18.04 by following the steps below:

```
$ wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
$ echo 'deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-10 main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
$ echo 'deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-10 main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt search 'clang-format'
...
clang-format-10/unknown 1:10.0.1~++20210314110130+ef32c611aa21-1~exp1~20210314220728.205 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
...
$ sudo apt install -y clang-format-10
$ clang-format-10 --version
Ubuntu clang-format version 10.0.1-++20210314110130+ef32c611aa21-1~exp1~20210314220728.205
```

You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66654073/9426588) for  more details.

Comment: sorry, I forgot adding comment. thanks a lot. it was great!

Comment: I have to do few more things: `sudo apt install -y libllvm10` before I can install clang-format-10, and `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang-format-10 /usr/bin/clang-format` after install clang-format-10